# Filtering rows in dataframe with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rows, plyr

I have a harmonized dataset about surveys conducted in different countries from 1960 to 2014. I want to drop the rows where two different surveys have been conducted in the same country in the same year. I am not sure how to use the filter verb in dplyr to drop the rows from the harmonized dataset.

```
Harm_data1 %>% 
group_by(country, survey, year, protest demo , protest fact) %>% 
filter(country >= 2 | year >=2)
```

Comment: `Harm_data1 %>% group_by(country, year) %>% filter(n() == 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you'd like that output to be piped into a new table? I believe what you have above would give the exact opposite of what you're requesting with is to say, it's only going to return those that are greater.  I'd do:

```
Harm_data1 %>% 
group_by(country, survey, year, protest demo , protest fact) %>% 
filter(country < 2 | year < 2)
```

Comment: Given countries are usually not stored as numbers and years are usually larger than 1, this will likely return a null set. You need to count the rows for each group.

Comment: countries are not stored as numbers that is the problem i thought , but can the count or distinct function in dplyr be used as condition to get the result for countries that are occurring more than once in the same year. ? would be grateful for any help :)

Comment: edit, I forgot to concatenate country and year. This would be better

   group_by(country) %>% mutate(Country_survey = n(paste(country, year)) %>% 
filter(Country_survey < 2)

Comment: I was also wondering if i could use the distinct function on columns country and year, would that take out the duplicates too ? 

Harm_data1 %>% 
        distinct(t_l2u_country_alpha_2,t_interview_year)

do you think this can also help in identifying cases where it has occurred in the same country more than once in the same year ?

Comment: pretty sure a values have to match up, but yes, you could use distinct that way.